# How can i open Microsoft Edge using Robot in Java?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class RickRoll {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        //create Robot
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        //runtime to open Microsoft Edge
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String command = "msedge.exe";
```

> What is below is supposed to run msedge

```
    runtime.exec(command);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.delay(1000);
}
```

}

> I dont understand why I keep getting an error instead of it running msedge. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, to be completely honest, there's a lot of things that look wrong in your code.  I would start with some simpler tutorials and work your way up to a point where you're comfortable using the Javadocs.  I'm not saying that to be mean, I just think you're setting yourself up to get frustrated if you don't yet know how to dig through the Javadocs yourself.  First issue is, you don't run programs with `Robot`.  That's not what it's for, and in your code, you don't actually even use the instance of `Robot` that you created, so you could actually just get rid of it.

Comment: You also use the command `msedge.exe`, which only works if msedge.exe is on your PATH environment variable.  If not, you have to give the full path to the program, which is typically `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it with cmd.
So it would be:

```
//runtime to open Microsoft Edge
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String command = "cmd.exe /C start microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com";
runtime.exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, including using class `java.lang.Runtime`, but I would say that is the least recommended.

As @CharlieArmstrong mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828485/how-can-i-open-microsoft-edge-using-robot-in-java#comment125213817_70828485), you need to execute file `msedge.exe`. If the folder containing that file is **not** in the PATH environment variable, you need to supply the full path to the file. You can use class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute the file.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:",
                              "Program Files (x86)",
                              "Microsoft",
                              "Edge",
                              "Application",
                              "msedge.exe");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path.toString());
        try {
            pb.start();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will open Edge at its home page. If you want to open a particular Web page, just add the URL.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:",
                          "Program Files (x86)",
                          "Microsoft",
                          "Edge",
                          "Application",
                          "msedge.exe");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path.toString(), "http://www.facebook.com");
    try {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use class [java.awt.Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html). If you just want to launch Edge, use method `open`. Again, if Edge is not on your PATH then you need to supply the full path.

```java
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class DesktopT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Path path = Paths.get("C:",
                                  "Program Files (x86)",
                                  "Microsoft",
                                  "Edge",
                                  "Application",
                                  "msedge.exe");
            File f = path.toFile();
            try {
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                desktop.open(f);
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to open a particular Web page then use method `browse`.
(Note that method `browse` will use your default Web browser which may not necessarily be Edge.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("https://www.yahoo.com");
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.browse(uri);
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException | IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that all the above code was run with JDK 17.0.2 on Windows 10. When run, the Java code launched Edge and terminated. However, class `Desktop` also launches the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) which may not terminate, if you are using an earlier JDK version. If that is the case then you can add the following as the last line in method `main`.

```java
java.lang.System.exit(0);
```

This line will terminate the JVM.